# convert gd resource type to stream image string context

Tags: php, base64, gd

How can convert gd resource type to stream image string context (exactly reverse [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) function)

I need the stream image string for convert it to the base64 by [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64_encode.php) function.

Without use any external or temp file.